# How to put a file into a variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd, var

I have something in a file and want to "put it" into a variable but I don't know how to do that.

This is my code right know:

```bat
@echo off
set image=<Log.txt.txt
echo %image% timeout 10000
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read the first line of batch file from the same batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143897/read-the-first-line-of-batch-file-from-the-same-batch-file) Specifically the part where you need to use `set /p image=<Log.txt` instead of just `set`.

Comment: This only puts the first line of a file into a variable. `set /p image=<Log.txt.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse text file. On empty line you should add end-line variable (**!LF!**).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


@rem TWO empty lines are required
set image=

for /f "skip=2 delims=] tokens=1,*" %%a in ('find /v /n "" Log.txt.txt') do (
if "%%b" neq "" (
set image=!image!%%b

) else (

set image=!image!!LF!!LF!

)

)
echo !image!
```

P.S. Single batch variable should have size limit. Change default code page corresponding your text file.